# Using nested for loop to find the second power of numbers using C

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to find the squares of numbers from -14 to 14 using nested for loops. I'm confused about how I should write the outer loop so far I just have this

```
    for(i=14;i>0;i--1)
        {
    for (k=i;k>=pow(i,2); k--)
    }
```

This is just for 0-14. Help pleaseee

Comment: `k >= pow(i, 2)` will never be true, since `k` starts at `i` and `i` is always less than its square (unless `i == 1` or `i == 0`)

Comment: Why do you think you need nested loops? If you want the square of a number, just print `pow(i, 2)` or `i * i`.

Comment: @Barmar: Presumably this is homework. But it does seem perverse to call `pow(i,2)` in the middle of a loop whose function is to search for i^2. Personally, I would use `j += 2*k-1`.

Comment: If you want to extend this solution to the negative numbers, just extend the outer loop: `for(i=14;i>-15;--i)`

Comment: @Beta I know it's homework, but I still couldn't make sense of the need for an inner loop.

Comment: `i--1` should just be `i--`

Comment: @Barmar: We're not building nested loops in order to find squares, we're searching for squares as a pretext for building nested loops. The inner loop is not necessary for finding a square, it is necessary for satisfying the teacher. *It's homework.*

Comment: The OP needs to post the actual assignment, because his vague description isn't clear enough to tell what he needs to do.

Comment: That is the assignment, its written exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the squares of numbers from -14 to 14 using nested for loops.

I'll assume this is an exercise about nested loops, more than a math problem, so that the inefficient but expected solution may be the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = -14; i <= 14; i++) {
        //       ^^^    ^^^^^
        int square = 0;
        // Take the absolute value of the outer index
        int factor = i < 0 ? -i : i;
        // Remember that i * i = i + i + ... + i (i times)
        for (int j = 0; j < factor; ++j) {
            //       ^      ^^^^^^
            square += factor;
        }
        printf("The square of %d is %d\n", i, square);
    } 
}
```